# Rx.js: get all results as array from promise lists

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

Here's the demo:

```js
var availableNews$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty').then(res => res.json()));
var pager$ = new Rx.Subject();
var fetchedNews$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(availableNews$, pager$, (news, pager) => news.slice((pager.current - 1) * pager.items_per_page, pager.items_per_page))
    .flatMap(id => id)
    .map(id => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`).then(res => res.json()))
    .concatMap(res => res));
pager$.subscribe(v => {
  console.log(v);
  document.querySelector('#pager').textContent = JSON.stringify(v);
});
fetchedNews$.subscribe(x => { 
  console.log(x);
  document.querySelector('#news').textContent = JSON.stringify(x);;
})
pager$.next({current: 1, items_per_page: 10})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
pager: <p id="pager"></p>
news: <p id="news"></p>
<p>the news return obserable instance instead of <em>array of fetched news</em> which is desired</p>
```

I do these things in code:

1, fetch top news feeds (availableNews$)

2, use pager to limit which feeds should be fetch (pager$)

3, fetch news which should be a array (fetchedNews$)

But I stunk at step 3, the results returned is the stream of each promiseObserable, not result of each promise concated as a array.

Thanks for help ^_^

--Edited--

I ask this question as [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1982#issuecomment-249835663) for the rxjs on github, and get a better solution. Here's the code:

```
const { Observable } = Rx;
const { ajax: { getJSON }} = Observable;

var availableNews$ = getJSON('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty');
var pager$ = new Rx.Subject();
var fetchedNews$ = Observable
  .combineLatest(availableNews$, pager$, (news, {current, items_per_page}) => {
    return news.slice((current - 1) * items_per_page, items_per_page);
  })
  .switchMap((ids) => Observable.forkJoin(ids.map((id) => {
    return getJSON(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`);
  })));

pager$.subscribe(v => {
  document.querySelector('#pager').textContent = JSON.stringify(v);
});

fetchedNews$.subscribe(stories => {
   document.querySelector('#news').textContent = JSON.stringify(stories);  
});

pager$.next({current: 1, items_per_page: 10})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a combination of two or three errors.

First, the lambda in your `combineLatest()` does not operate on the array of news ids, but on a single item containing the array. The `flatmap()` is therefore unnecessary, as is the `concatMap()`.

Second, you don't need to create `Observable` from `fetch()`, as

third, the `combineLatest()` you have does not give a Promise that is fullfilled when the news are loaded, but when the availableNews and pager are loaded. So you have to make a third `Observable` with `combineLatest()`, but from the Array of `fetch()` Promises. You then subscribe to that in your second `subscribe()`, like this:

```js
var availableNews$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty').then(res => res.json()));
var pager$ = new Rx.Subject();
var fetchedNews$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(availableNews$, pager$, (news, pager) =>
  Rx.Observable.combineLatest.apply(this, news.slice((pager.current - 1) * pager.items_per_page, pager.items_per_page)
    .map(id => fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json?print=pretty`).then(res => res.json()))));

pager$.subscribe(v => {
  document.querySelector('#pager').textContent = JSON.stringify(v);
});

fetchedNews$.subscribe(x => { 
  x.subscribe(a => {
    document.querySelector('#news').textContent = JSON.stringify(a);
  });
})
pager$.next({current: 1, items_per_page: 10})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
pager: <p id="pager"></p>
news: <p id="news"></p>
<p>the news return obserable instance instead of <em>array of fetched news</em> which is desired</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explains and code!  so the `combineLatest` can be used for fetching `feature` data.    But I am confusing that `combineLatest` in the [rxjs doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) is received two obserable, while your code is combining array of promise return by `map(id => fetch...`.

Comment: And it would be better if we don't need two level of `subscribe`.

Comment: For now, I wrap the `fetchedNews$` into another obserable by `Rx.Obserable.create(observer => fetchedNews$.subscribe(news$ => news$.subscribe(news => observer.next(news))))`